# How to overwrite StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect to add error logging?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, error-handling, redis

I have this code

```
internal class Cache : ICache
{
    private ConnectionMultiplexer mux;
    private ILogger logger;

    public Cache(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task SetKeyValue(string key, string value)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        Connect();
        .
        .
        await this.mux.GetDatabase().StringSetAsync(key, value, expiry);

    }

    private void Connect()
    {

        this.mux = StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
        this.mux.ConnectionFailed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            this.logger.LogError(args.Exception, $"Connection Failed: {args.Exception.ToString()}");
        };
        this.mux.InternalError += (sender, args) =>
        {
            this.logger.LogError(args.Exception, $"Internal Error: {args.Exception.ToString()}");
        };

    }
}
```

My goal is that every time *StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect* fails to connect and await *this.mux.GetDatabase().StringSetAsync(key, value, expiry)* fails to set value I want to log the exception object in *logger*.

This is what I have done so far

```
private void Connect()
{

    this.mux = StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
    this.mux.ConnectionFailed += (sender, args) =>
    {
        this.logger.LogError(args.Exception, $"Connection Failed: {args.Exception.ToString()}");
    };
    this.mux.InternalError += (sender, args) =>
    {
        this.logger.LogError(args.Exception, $"Internal Error: {args.Exception.ToString()}");
    };

}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I am thinking overriding/overloading the connect method of *StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect* or maybe use the fact that it is a partial class, but I am not sure how to do that.

Currently this is what is does

```
public sealed partial class ConnectionMultiplexer : IInternalConnectionMultiplexer // implies : IConnectionMultiplexer and : IDisposable
{
    .
    .
    .
    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connect(string configuration, TextWriter log = null)
    {
        return Connect(ConfigurationOptions.Parse(configuration), log);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```